# XSLT odd behivior with a xsl:template

Tags: xml, xslt

can someone explain to me this strange output i got here.

[image]

Comment: i do not understand why i'm getting this output.

Comment: In general, it's best to provide code and text, not just pictures when asking questions. The reason why it's generating output with just those numbers is due to the default template rules, which will recursively process the content and emit the values of the `text()` nodes. https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#built-in-rule